# From where i can Get Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7

as all know Magneto 1 is no longer supported by Magento team  but I want 1.9 for testing an extension which I have to migrate on magneto 2 if anyone know any repo where I can get please provide me if anyone have download setup then please upload on google drive and send me link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get latest magento1 version from the below link

https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/archive/1.9.4.5.zip

Comment: thank you so much sir..